# Vue js 3 Reactivity confused with data change methods in component api

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-component, reactive

hi guys i have a quick question about changing the data in vue3 reactive data let me show you my code so you get what is the idea

```
const packageInfo = reactive({
    data:[]
})
```

this is my code sample data for package is like this

```
data =>
[
    {
       id:"ship_id"
       ship:"ship_number"
       products:
              [
                 {product:"product_name",id:"product_id"},
                 {product:"product_name2",id:"product_id2"}
              ]
    }
]
```

so basically I have two functions one for removing package with id and one for removing product with id my package function works perfectly and removes data also effects the UI I mean the change effects the component and removes data from table too

but for product delete with id I'm facing problems data gets deleted but its not effecting the component and UI this is my code

```
async function deletePackage(pack){
    let { data } = await axios.delete(`/packages/${pack.id}`);
    if(data == 1){
        packageInfo.data = packageInfo.data.filter(function( obj ) {
            return obj.id !== pack.id;
        });
    }
    
}
async function deleteProduct(pack,product){
    
    let tmData = packageInfo.data
    tmData[tmData.indexOf(pack)].products = tmData[tmData.indexOf(pack)].products.filter(function( obj ) {
            return obj.id !== product.id;
    });
    packageInfo.data = tmData
    // packageInfo.data[packageInfo.data.indexOf(pack)].products = packageInfo.data[packageInfo.data.indexOf(pack)].products.filter(function( obj ) {
    //         return obj.id !== product.id;
    // });
}
```

in second function I'm trying to remove the product with same id only not total package or total products

can you please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

EDIT:

Here is how I'm using packageInfo in UI

```
<ScannerTable :table-data="packageInfo"/>
```

And in ScannerTable Component

```
const props = defineProps({
    tableData:{
        default:[]
    }
})
```

I'm using this to get data everything works perfectly even the package removal works and updates in templates table but products removal not works !

**EDIT 2:**
even when I changed the way of showing to show if show value is true only still its not effective
am I missing something let me show you one image this first array of objects which is data is totally reactive but the second layer which is products is not reactive and changes are not effected in UI

[image]

**EDIT 3**

I Found out this way I can change the data and the products get deleted from the table so basically I'm changing the parent shipment of product and calling Tick which changes so basically product is not reactive but can someone explain me why ?! I'm getting so confused even I used ref()
for my show but still not effective

```
packageInfo.data.forEach(async(dasdata,i)=>{
        if(dasdata.id == pack.id){
            packageInfo.data[i].show = false
            dasdata.products.forEach(async(prods,j)=>{
                if(prods.id == product.id){
                    packageInfo.data[i].products[j].show = false;
                }
            })
            await nextTick()
            packageInfo.data[i].show = true
        }
    })
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfectly on my device. Would you please share the UI and template part too?

Comment: @Raeisi weird ill update the question with more info

Comment: Did you set the `key` property in your loop? `<div v-for="p in tableData.data" :key="p.id">`

Comment: Yes everything is working my friend data is showing perfectly but when I remove data inside the reactive packageInfo it takes effect only for 1 layer but for second object layor which is products its not effecting UI and data still there as image I shared when I changing the show for data object its effecting but when I change show in products array its not effecting UI at all @Raeisi

Comment: I have re-implemented your code 3 times and all of them work properly. I think your problem goes around passing props or poor rendering UI. I can share my codes if it helps. To figure your issue out, I need to see your ScannerTable codes. Further more, where do you remove items; in the parent or scanner table? Where the delete commands are originated?

Comment: @Raeisi if its possible for you to share a code snippet ?! because my code is too long to share in here also I'm removing items in parent and I'm expecting to get effected in child which is scanner table some data gets effected some not ! really thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I've done to simulate your issue.

```html
<template>
<div>
  <ul v-for="pkg in packageInfo.data" :key="pkg.id">
  <li>
    {{ pkg.ship }}
    <span @click="removePackage(pkg)" style="color: red; cursor: pointer">X</span>
  </li>
  <ul v-for="prod in pkg.products" :key="prod.id">
    <li>
      {{ prod.product }}
      <span @click="removeProduct(pkg,prod)" style="color: red; cursor: pointer">X</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
</div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { reactive } from 'vue';

const packageInfo = reactive({
  data: [
    {
      id: 'ship_id1',
      ship: 'ship_number1',
      products:
        [
          { product: 'product_name1_1', id: 'product_id1' },
          { product: 'product_name1_2', id: 'product_id2' },
        ],
    },
    {
      id: 'ship_id2',
      ship: 'ship_number2',
      products:
        [
          { product: 'product_name2_1', id: 'product_id11' },
          { product: 'product_name2_2', id: 'product_id22' },
        ],
    },
  ],
});

function removePackage(pack: any) {
  packageInfo.data = packageInfo.data.filter(x => x.id !== pack.id);
}

function removeProduct(pack: any, product:any) {
  pack.products = pack.products.filter(x => x.id !== product.id);
  // let tmData = packageInfo.data
  // tmData[tmData.indexOf(pack)].products = tmData[tmData.indexOf(pack)].products.filter(function( obj ) {
  //   return obj.id !== product.id;
  // });
  // packageInfo.data = tmData
}
</script>
```

I think your issue goes around passing props or there is something wrong with your rendering mechanism.

I have another implementation (ScannerTable in a separate file), but that's not the case.

Comment: the way i was using the removeProduct function was a mess and using pack.products just fixed that thanks a lot ! but Im still confused why accessing it directly from packageInfo.data[index] removes reactivity from products not packages !