# Issue with reactivity in Vue 3.0 when dynamically removing items from an array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm facing a reactivity problem in my Vue 3.0 application. I'm trying to allow users to remove items from an array, but after removing an item, the view doesn't update automatically.

Here's my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Item List</h2>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        {{ item.name }} <button @click="removeItem(item.id)">Remove</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const items = ref([
  { id: 1, name: 'Item 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Item 2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Item 3' },
  // ... more items ...
]);

function removeItem(itemId) {
  const index = items.value.findIndex(item => item.id === itemId);
  if (index !== -1) {
    items.value.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
</script>
```

After clicking the "Remove" button, the item in the array is correctly removed, but the view doesn't refresh to reflect the change. Is there a way to force Vue to reactively update the view after removing an item? How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76800295/vue-js-3-reactivity-confused-with-data-change-methods-in-component-api/76812161?noredirect=1#comment135460342_76812161